# If white light travels from glass to vacuum will there be dispersion?

Tags: geometric-optics

Will light disperse on traveling from glass to vacuum considering incident angle that is less than the critical angle (i.e. no total internal reflection)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Dispersion occurs if light travels from one media into another that has a different refractive index *for that particular wavelength.* Since vacuum by definition has a refractive index of 1, and glass has refractive index of ~1.5 (for visible wavelengths), then light should experience dispersion when exiting the glass. This is assuming the glass is a simple flat interface and we're in the geometric optics regime.

More here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_(optics)#Material_dispersion_in_optics

Comment: This also assumes the light is not parallel to the normal of the interface

Comment: @Aaron Stevens Why did you say 'parallel to the normal' rather than just saying 'normal' to the interface? Just curious. I think I would have just said at normal incidence.

Comment: @Aaron Stevens Though no interface is truly flat and no beam is truly straight so there will always be some dispersion at any angle.